# Dynamically change QStyle at runtime?

Tags: qt, qstyle

I want to tweak the existing style at runtime, specifically QStyle::PM_ToolBarIconSize. Can this be done? As far as I can tell, you can only inherit QStyle and override pixelMetric().

Edit 1: In the specific case of QStyle::PM_ToolBarIconSize, I could use QToolBar::setIconSize, but that would set the icon size for just a single toolbar instance. I want to change the underlying style hint to affect all toolbars everywhere with one fell swoop. And QStyle::PM_ToolBarIconSize may not be the only style I want to tweak, it's just the first one I'm looking at that just so happens to have a "change this instance's icon size" function.

Edit 2: I can't just make a new style subclass because the current style is already a custom style based on style sheets. There are several styles that a user can choose from. I don't want to create a bunch of new styles just so I can tweak a couple of toolbar icon or menu height size settings.

Comment: How about [QToolBar::setIconSize](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html#iconSize-prop)

Comment: Yeah, but that's not quite what I was looking for. I have, hopefully, clarified my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the exact purpose of QProxyStyle.

Answer (score 0):

Why not overriding QStyle then? Your subclass would return an icon size (via pixelMetric) which depends on a settable parameter of your QStyle.

As Qt does not have a dynamic QStyle mechanism, it is better to create a new style instance with the changed icon size, then set it to the QApplication, rather than altering the current style.

Comment: This is not a viable option for me. I have further clarified my question as to why this is so.